# Alert Box not working in intel xdk

Tags: javascript, html, intel-xdk

this is my code

```
<button class="btn widget uib_w_2 d-margins btn-danger" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/button" data-ver="1" id="btn" onclick="show()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search button-icon-left" data-position="left"></i>Show</button>
    </div>
<script>

      function show(){
          intel.xdk.notification.alert("your name is:","tiltle","ok");
      }
      </script>
  </body>
```

when i run in the emulator is not working what should  to do !!

Comment: are you calling show() anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Cordova notification` plugin instead, the `intel.xdk.notification` plugin is deprecated.

The Cordova notification plugin works the same way, you have to add this plugin in Intel XDK plugin management and then test on emulator:

```
navigator.notification.alert(message, alertCallback, [title], [buttonName])
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-dialogs

Answer (score -1):

```
intel.xdk.notification.alert("your name is:","tiltle","ok");
```

from what I'm seeing, you misspelled title. See if that fixes it.

Comment: that's just a string, not syntax